# Using global variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, global

I am new to JavaScript. So please forgive me if this is a silly question.

I have declared a global variable in my HTML based site as follows:

```
var myVar = "global"; // Declare a global variable, value of myVar will vary
```

Now, under actual circumstances, the value of myVar will be varying as per various parameters. I want my code to perform different tasks for different values of myVar. I have followed the following if/else layout:

```
if (myVar == "global") {
    //Perform task 1
} else if (myVar == 2) {
    //Perform task 2
} else {
    //perform task 3
}
```

These are the doubts I have: is the syntax I have used in the if/else layout correct? I had tried the above if else condition with only the first if condition in place and I was unable to get the desired output for myVar. Is there anything I could have done wrong or missed out?

My apologies for this silly question again, I am just a novice to JS

Comment: What problems did you encounter? Because the syntax of your if-block is correct

Answer (score 1):

Your `ifs` syntax is good. The problem come from the declaration of your `myVar`. You added a `<` in the first `<script>` element. remove it.

```
       <script type = "text/javascript">
        var myVar = "global"; // Declare a global   variable,                                       value of myVar will vary

  </script>
```

Instead of

```
             <script type = "text/javascript">
       < 
     var myVar = "global"; // Declare a global   variable,                                       value of myVar will vary

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your global variable is declared in a seperate script. It can referenced through the window accessor.

For example:

```
window.myVar
```

Edit: code syntax

Answer (score 0):

The reason only the first one is working is because you need to set myVar to an input, not a static value:

```
var myVar = prompt("What would you like the name of your variable to be?");
```

I hope that works!